# Insert data into table derived from other table using stored procedure

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I use the following sql code to insert data into a table after deriving from other table. I am not so expert at advanced PL/SQL. I want to build a stored procedure that achieves the same thing I am able to do with this SQL code. The idea is that I will just execute the procedure and it will load data rather than running this code again and again. I tried some examples but all give error on compiling and most examples are SQL server format.

```
Insert into TABLE(ID,NBR,VALUE,DESCRIPTION,STATUS,FILLER,SOURCE_SYSTEM,DATE_LOADED_TIMESTAMP)
SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1,1,2) as ID,
SUBSTR(COLUMN1,3,3) as NBR,
SUBSTR(COLUMN1,6,14) as VAUE,
SUBSTR(COLUMN1,20,30) as DESCRIPTION,
SUBSTR(COLUMN1,50,1) as STATUS,
SUBSTR(COLUMN1,51,2) as FILLER,
SOURCE_SYSTEM as SOURCE_SYSTEM,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE_LOADED_TIMESTAMP
from TMP_TABLE;
```

Comment: So put the above `insert` statement into a procedure. What isn't working?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson I was just running in wrong syntax did not know it was this easy. Just want to know if i can write like extra line to truncate the table before inserting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
This may help you:


        create or replace procedure your_procedure_name
        as
        begin 
        Truncate table TABLE;
        Insert into TABLE(ID,NBR,VALUE,DESCRIPTION,STATUS,FILLER,SOURCE_SYSTEM,DATE_LOADED_TIMESTAMP)
        SELECT SUBSTR(COLUMN1,1,2) as ID,
        SUBSTR(COLUMN1,3,3) as NBR,
        SUBSTR(COLUMN1,6,14) as VAUE,
        SUBSTR(COLUMN1,20,30) as DESCRIPTION,
        SUBSTR(COLUMN1,50,1) as STATUS,
        SUBSTR(COLUMN1,51,2) as FILLER,
        SOURCE_SYSTEM as SOURCE_SYSTEM,
        CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE_LOADED_TIMESTAMP
        from TMP_TABLE;

    COMMIT;
        end;

Test with:

    BEGIN
       your_procedure_name;
    END;
```

Comment: What if I want to truncate the table TABLE before inserting can I just add extra line before insert?